# Photodiode op amp circuit, incorrect or correct output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, layout, photodiode

[image]

I am using the S12053-02 APD and the ADA4817 op amp. I'm not really sure if I'm getting the correct output or if the configuration I have is the best. I am trying to get a near 1 to 10 nA to mV, so if the APD is measuring 80nA the op amp should output 800mV. I have this circuit breadboarded at the moment and hooked up to an oscilloscope, and so far it is behaving like the LT.SPice sim. Any thoughts?

Comment: The schematic is a little messy. But I recognize it. I think [the datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4817-1_4817-2.pdf) makes note of the fact that the input bias currents are in the vicinity of your I2 source, though. Perhaps more than an order of magnitude higher, over operating range. Is that the low end of what you actually need to observe? How/why did you select the 2.5 pA in your schematic?

Comment: Hamamatsu's technical note **Si photodiodes** (https://www.hamamatsu.com/content/dam/hamamatsu-photonics/sites/documents/99_SALES_LIBRARY/ssd/si_pd_kspd9001e.pdf) presents a number of examples showing how the user can connect a Si photodiode and opamp (Section 3 How to use, subsections 3-1 Connection to an opamp and 3-2 Application circuit examples).

Comment: What makes this document especially suited to your needs, is that the recommendations on PhD-opamp connection are organized around applications for which the setup is to be designed, as ultra-low-light detection circuit, light-level integration circuit, illuminometer, absortionmeter etc. First study this document, then select the most appropriate prototype, and start your design job with adapting the example circuit to your specific task. If the question arises in the course of this work, I promise it will invite useful answers from experts.

Comment: @periblepsis 2.5nA is within the range of the dark current min and max of the APD (.2nA and 5nA). I need it to be sensitive, so far from what the real circuit is outputting it seems to be doing so. So if I cover the APD with a dark cloth or shut off the room lights, 25mV is what the op amp is outputting, so that means that the APD is reading 2.5nA, theoretically

Comment: @V.V.T thanks for the document, I'll read up on it and report back!

Comment: @nano_m You may also want to read anything by Phil Hobbs. For example, [Photodiode Front Ends: The REAL Story](https://zeus.phys.uconn.edu/halld/hpd-3-2005/frontends.pdf) and [Getting Photodetection Right](https://electrooptical.net/static/oldsite/talks/GettingPDRight11.pdf). He also has a good book (which I prefer over those earlier works) called *"Building Electro-Optical Systems"*.

Comment: @periblepsis thank you, I'll read up on it!

Comment: @nano_m I worked with him for a year or two. I was working on systems that were reaching down into hundreds of atto-amps (the point where *boson flocking* becomes an important noise consideration.) He's sharp and helped me get there. We were able to discriminate (detect) down to a few fempto-amps of resolution. All I needed at the time.

Comment: @nano_m I should also add that Hamamatsu was also a partner in the process. I was able to convince them (not easy to do at the time -- no idea about now) to provide photodiodes as dies in a waffle pack. (Epoxy leaks like a sieve.) They, at the time, had never previously done that and made a unique exception in my case. So I owe them, dearly, for their willingness to work with our team. Good folks!